# GitLab Container scanning runs without being called

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am currently using the GitLab Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml template to perform container scans. I am using `extends: container_scanning` in each job I want to run the scan.

```
include:
  - template: Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

example_container_scan:
  extends: container_scanning
```

When the ci pipeline runs it will kick off the `example_container_scan` job AND another `container_scanning` job.

In fact, the `container_scanning` job will kick off even if it is not mentioned in any job. Simply by importing the template, kicks off.

My question is, how do you disable the extra `container_scanning` job from running? In other words, I only want the `example_container_scan` job to run.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround was to take the `Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml`, add it to the project repo and making the `container_scanning` job hidden (`.container_scanning`).

```
# include the Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml from the local project
include:
  - Security/Container-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

example_container_scan:
  extends: .container_scanning
```